# Moving an existing 14.04.2 LTS Ubuntu VM to Amazon EC2

Tags: 14.04, webserver, amazon-ec2

I have an Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS based server installation that runs a ruby on rails application accessible over the local network. Currently it runs in either VM Player / VM Server / vSphere.

What do I need to do in order to prepare the image and get it to run on Amazon EC2, so that it boots properly?
I tried using the EC2 importimage service and although it does import, the instance wasn't reachable when you start it up.

Does the Ubuntu installation itself need packages added so it runs, or is it a matter of importing the disks correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I had a similar issue, and what ended up being the problem was an incorrect aki.  Make sure you are using the correct one for the region you are using.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedKernels.html